# Jetty Not Picking Up Port Option

Tags: java, jetty

I am trying to run jetty on port 9000, and I have tried the command line mechanism specified obn many sites including this one, but Jetty seems to refuse to pick up the port option

```
$ java -Djetty.port=9000 -jar start.jar etc/jetty.xml
2014-04-04 08:12:53.368:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.1.1.v20140108
2014-04-04 08:12:53.379:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/home/david/Jetty/jetty-distribution-9.1.1.v20140108/webapps/] at interval 1
2014-04-04 08:12:53.386:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED ServerConnector@50bbaeee{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    ...
```

How do I fix this and run on port 9000?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Jetty to run on a different port by setting the jetty.port Property on the command line:

`> java -jar start.jar jetty.port=8081`

As alternatives, you can set this property in the start.ini file or by editing the use of the property in the etc/jetty-http.xml configuration file. This works by defining a property that the etc/jetty-http.xml configuration file uses to inject a port value into the ServerConnector defined there. For more information see the Quickstart Configuration Guide and Configuring Connectors.

Those information are in this page here - http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.0.6.v20130930/quickstart-running-jetty.html